# Vb.net 2008 with SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I need some serious help with vb.net system. I'm developing a desktop ordering system, my process flow goes like Customer--->Order------->Invoice------>Payment, NB* all this is happening through an employee, employee member makes an order on behalf of the customer.

So what I want is that throughout the process flow, like once you're done adding customer details, it goes to ORDER, so I want it to carry the same CustomerID for the customer I'm busy with.

Can someone please help me with a startup code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Customer`, `Order`, `Invoice` and `Payment` are classes:

```
 Ord = New Order(Cust.CustomerID)
```

Basically just pass the currently Cust ID to the Order constructor when you are creating it. If you need to create 'blank' orders, overload the constructor:

```
Class Order
    Public Sub New()
       ...
    End Sub

    Public Sub New (Cust As Long)
      ...
    End Sub
```

If that is not possible for some strange reason, make it possible to load a customer via a method:

```
 Ord = New Order()
 Ord.LoadCust(Cust.CustomerID)
```

------------- Edit for procedural version -----------------------

```
 PUBLIC ThisCustID As String  ' (?)  THIS is a global variable if declared
                              '  outside a SUB like in a module
```

.... customer does stuff

```
 ThisCustID = ID_OF_NEW_CUST       ' what was just saved in db
```

far away in Order module:

```
 Public Sub MakeNewOrder()
     ' has access to ThisCustID, but should not change it
 End Sub
```

or:

```
Public Sub MakeNewOrder(CustID)
     ' pass the current customer and avoid a global variable.
```

Rinse and repeat for `ThisOrderID` to pass to Invoice

Comment: Can't I do without using a class? Like for my staffID that stays the same through out the process flow, I've created a subroutine under a module and on the Login Button, I coded : If dr.read = true then call that subroutine = dr(0), then when staff has logged onto the system, his StaffID stays the same through out, so how do I do the same for customerID?

Comment: then just make a global variable `ThisCustomerID` assign it the value for the current cust in your customer process and then have the order process access that variable.  Hard to give an elegant solution for procedural programming without seeing some code.  Or are these actors all different EXEs or something similar?

Comment: I did make it Global Variable.  Public Sub CustID(byval CustID as String)    conn.close conn.open  query = "select cust_id from customers where cust_id='" & custID. Command.sqlcommand(query,conn) etc. But now I don't have a clue on how to call it in the Order Form

Comment: That snippet makes no sense.  if there is a global VARIABLE named CustomerID (or CustID) why is it passed as an arg?  The SUB is silly, because it is told to get the CustID from Customers Where CustID == the one passed in - why LOOK UP something you already know and have?.  It does nothing, it returns nothing. It also sounds like you are confusing VARIABLES with SUBS.  Short answer: why not treat CustID like you do StaffID...mimic how you have that working.